# PCH: how to locally enforce it still builds without?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So if you use precompiled headers includes are "injected" into all files.
In extreme cases you end up with cpp files without any includes (other than explicit or implicit stdafx.h).

Is there a way to locally enforce that the files have proper includes and are still compilable without PCH?

By local I mean not relying on a CI system to do that check.
Maybe a Visual Studio extension can do the trick?

Comment: I don't understand your concerns. To my knowledge you always need to explicitly include the precompiled header file. I don't see how you includes can not be "proper". If you disable the PCH in your build configuration your code should still compile - slower but without any problems. The only problem that may occur is the other way around when not all cpp files include the precompiled header but you will be warned about this as well. Please explain what your actual concerns are and if possible provide an example.

Comment: You can force include (/FI) the pch header file.
Then you can easily switch between PCH and non-PCH build.
Especially if your project files are generated.

Comment: So you want to make sure that your code compiles with and without PCH (using force include) before submitting it into your source code management system? May I ask why you don't just test both builds? I am not quite getting the use case.